# How to use diffClamp in reanimated 2?

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I am trying to hide and show the header based on the scroll event from reanimated 2 **useAnimatedScrollHandler** and I need to use the **diffClamp** so whenever the user scrolls up the header should be shown in less time than the whole scroll event **contentOffset.y** value but the problem is diffClamp is I think from **reanimated v1** and I need to use useAnimatedStyle hook in order to animate styles in **reanimated v2** and finally it gives an error.

Can someone please help with it?

Comment: Post code on what you have and fixes you have tried without success

Answer (score 5):

```
const clamp = (value, lowerBound, upperBound) => {
    "worklet";
    return Math.min(Math.max(lowerBound, value), upperBound);
};

const scrollClamp = useSharedValue(0);

const scrollHandler = useAnimatedScrollHandler({
    onScroll: (event, ctx) => {

        const diff = event.contentOffset.y - ctx.prevY;

        scrollClamp.value = clamp(scrollClamp.value + diff, 0, 200);

    },
    onBeginDrag: (event, ctx) => {
        ctx.prevY = event.contentOffset.y;
    }
});

const RStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {

    const interpolateY = interpolate(
        scrollClamp.value,
        [0, 200],
        [0, -200],
        Extrapolate.CLAMP
    )

    return {
        transform: [
            { translateY: interpolateY }
        ]
    }
})
```

Comment: If this is the code to your original question, it would make more sense to edit the original question with the code added to it

Comment: Great answer, this is also a helpful thread on the issue - https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/discussions/1573

Comment: theres no update on prevY so it wont work as expected.

Comment: const scrollHandler = useAnimatedScrollHandler({
        onScroll: (event, ctx) => {
            const diff = event.contentOffset.y - ctx.prevY;
            scrollClamp.value = clamp(scrollClamp.value + diff, 0, headerHeight);
            ctx.prevY = event.contentOffset.y;
        },
      onBeginDrag: (event, ctx) => {
        ctx.prevY = event.contentOffset.y
      }
    });